# How to show navigation bar top and tool bar below when showing uiimage in full screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

```
-(void)imageFullScreen:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{
        modalCon = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        modalCon.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        modalCon.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:modalCon.view.frame];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.image = self.mImageView.image;

        [modalCon.view addSubview:imageView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *modalTap =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissModalView:)];
        [modalCon.view addGestureRecognizer:modalTap];


        [self.delegate showFullScreen:modalCon];
        return;
    }
```

The method showFullScreen:modalCon will show the modalViewController(modalCon) and on touch of image shown, it will dismiss. But when image is full screen, the navigation bar is not shown (black bars come both above and below the image) like this:
[image]

But I want same behaviour as iOS photos app does on click of any photo in library where a navigation bar comes up and tool bar down with multiple buttons comes and edit, back, share, delete options come like this :[image]

Comment: what have you tried to add them ? The image is displayed in aspect fit mode, hence the black bars. PLs show the code related to adding nav bar and toolbar to view controller.

Comment: Thats what I am looking for. How to add that navigation bar and tool bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try this https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser
Credits to Michael Waterfall

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view from storyboard
2. Embedded it with navigation bar
3. Setup title and edit button in viewcontroller file
4. Add image view and and uiview
5. UIview contains tableview and the 3 buttons
6. table view you have to manage scroll and frame programatically